# Map a curried function over an array using lenses

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, lenses

I have an object and want to update each value in an array inside of the object using some other object member. Here is what I am attempting:

```js
import * as R from 'ramda'

const obj = {
    array: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    incrementBy: 0
};

const doIncrement = R.curry((inc,val) => {
    return val+inc;
});

const incrementLens = R.lensProp('incrementBy');
const setIncrementToOne = R.set(incrementLens,1);

const newObj = setIncrementToOne(obj);

const arrayLens = R.lensProp('array');

const incrementA = R.over(arrayLens, R.map(doIncrement(1)));

const incrementB = R.pipe(
    setIncrementToOne,
    R.chain(
        R.over(arrayLens, R.map(doIncrement)),
        R.view(incrementLens)
    )
)

console.log(JSON.stringify(incrementA(newObj))); // works: {"array":[2,3,4],"incrementBy":1}
console.log(JSON.stringify(incrementB(obj))); // does not work (TypeError: Cannot read property 'fantasy-land/map' of undefined)
```

Version A obviously works as I access the array directly and map my curried function over it. In version B, however, I am unsure of the order of things; what I've tried now does not appear to pass the value from `R.view` to the curried function appropriately.

(NB. that the use case is more complex, I would just like to understand how I can work with curried functions, maps and lenses simultaneously.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `R.chain` is applied to functions - `chain(f, g)(x)` is equivalent to `f(g(x))(x)` - applying function `g` on value 'x', returning, and then applying function `f` on the result of `g(x)` and then on value `x`.

In your case:

- `g(x)` (`R.view(incrementLens)`) is 1
- `f` (`R.over(arrayLens, R.map(doIncrement))`) is a function that waits for the value (not another function)

Applying `f` (`R.over...`) on `g(x)` applies a lens on a non object value, and even if it was an object the result would have been another value, which means that you don't have a function to apply to on the result of `setIncrementToOne` in the pipe.

The result of `g(x)` in this case needs to be a function, that can be used by `R.over` with the `arraylens` - to get the `R.over(arrayLens, R.map(R.add(1)))`, which is identical to `incrementA`.

Note: I've replaced `doIncrement` with `R.add`, which does the same thing.

```js
const obj = {
  array: [1, 2, 3],
  incrementBy: 0
};

const incrementLens = R.lensProp('incrementBy');
const setIncrementToOne = R.set(incrementLens, 1);
const newObj = setIncrementToOne(obj);
const arrayLens = R.lensProp('array');

const incrementB = R.pipe(
  setIncrementToOne,
  R.chain(
    R.over(arrayLens),
    R.pipe(R.view(incrementLens), R.add, R.map)
  )
)

const incrementA = R.over(arrayLens, R.map(R.add(1)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(incrementA(newObj))); // works: {"array":[2,3,4],"incrementBy":1}
console.log(JSON.stringify(incrementB(obj))); // works: {"array":[2,3,4],"incrementBy":1}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice!  One correction: `chain (f, g) (x)` is really equivalent to `f (g (x)) (x)`.  The version in the text, `f (g (x), x)`,  works with Ramda's magic currying, but would fail with non-curried functions.

Comment: Perfect. I have yet to come to terms with "functions as data", I think that is what confused me, and this answer brings me a ways toward understanding.